# Rails Validate no White Space in User Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to validate that a user name has no white/blank spaces for my Users.  Is there a built in validation that does this?  Or what is the best way to do this.  Seems like it would be a pretty common requirement.

Comment: I bet there is a rails function, but I don't do web development.  My best guess is just checking if `st == st[/\s/]`.  If the string has even one white space character it will be false.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I would try [format validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format):

```
validates :username, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/ }
```

as most of the time when you don't want whitespaces in username you also don't want other characters.

Or when you really only need to check for whitespace, use `without` instead:

```
validates :username, format: { without: /\s/ }
```

Full documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_format_of (`validates ... format: {}` is the same as `validates_format_of ...`)

Comment: You will also probably want to specify a specific validation message as well: `validates :username, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/, message: 'cannot contain whitespace' }`

Answer (score 6):

I believe you will have to create a custom validator:

```
validate :check_empty_space

def check_empty_space
  if self.attribute.match(/\s+/)
    errors.add(:attribute, "No empty spaces please :(")
  end
end
```

Comment: Just `\s`, the `+` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

In your User model add validation. validates :username, format: { without: /\s/ } will remove white/blank spaces for your Users. You can even add a message alerting the user that their username contains whitespace.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 validates :username, format: { without: /\s/, message: "must contain no spaces" }

end
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 1):

You can use **before_validation** callback to strip whitespace

```
class User
  before_validation :strip_blanks

  protected

  def strip_blanks
    self.username = self.username.strip
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

[MurifoX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023609/murifox)'s answer is better, but regarding it being a common requirement, i think this is more often used:

[validates :presence](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Comment: `presence` simply checks that the attribute is not blank, it does nothing to validate the format (i.e. containing no whitespace) of the attribute itself.